# Posting array elements to different divs using for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to make a basic quiz and have become stuck on what I'm sure is a silly problem but as I'm only new to javascript, I'm struggling to work it out.

I have an array that will hold my questions and I have a for loop that I want to use to cycle through each element in the array in turn. On each iteration I want the question held in that slot of the array to be posted to a different div.

I've already made the divs in advance as quest0, quest1 etc. one for each slot of the array. But I've had no luck successfully posting all 10 sample questions.

```
var quizQuestions = new Array("Sample question 1","Sample question 2","Sample question 3","Sample question 4","Sample question 5","Sample question 6","Sample question 7","Sample question 8","Sample question 9","Sample question 10");

function questionMe(){
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  //var testvar = quizQuestions[i];
  document.getElementById("quest"+i).innerHTML = document.write(quizQuestions[i] + "<br>");
  //document.getElementById("quest"+i).innerHTML = testvar;  
}
}
```

I have the function being called using body onload, and the body is otherwise populated by nothing but the divs (quest0, quest1 etc.).

I have tried two seperate posting methods: the document.write method and also trying to post a variable using the getElementById but I've had no luck getting my questions out with either.

I'm not sure if I've made a mistake with the posting methods or if it's a problem with the ("quest"+i) that I've been using or maybe even something else entirely.

I'm afraid I just can't see where I'm going wrong with this and I'd really appreciate some fresh and more knowledgeable eyes taking a glance at it for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `document.write()` . . . using `innerHTML` will automatically add the text into the `<div>`.  Try changing it to this:

```
document.getElementById("quest" + i).innerHTML = quizQuestions[i] + "<br>";
```

Also, just on a side note, for your `for`, use this:

```
for(i=0; i<quizQuestions.length; i++) {
```

That way, if the length of your array ever changes, you won't have to change your code.

**NOTE:** If that still doesn't work, add your HTML and the rest of your JS to your question so that we can see it . . . it could be an issue with how that is coded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your initial markup. I assume you created your divs like this:

```
<div id="questN" />
```

That doesn't work*, you should replace it with this:

```
<div id="questN"></div>
```

Example:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="quest0"></div>
  <div id="quest1"></div>
  <div id="quest2"></div>
  <div id="quest3"></div>
  <div id="quest4"></div>
  <div id="quest5"></div>
  <div id="quest6"></div>
  <div id="quest7"></div>
  <div id="quest8"></div>
  <div id="quest9"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var quizQuestions = ["Sample question 1","Sample question 2","Sample question 3","Sample question 4","Sample question 5","Sample question 6","Sample question 7","Sample question 8","Sample question 9","Sample question 10"];

function questionMe(){
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.getElementById("quest"+i).innerHTML = quizQuestions[i];
  }
}
questionMe();
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/uROhUJE/1/edit

PS: Don't use `document.write` when you have a perfectly good alternative in `innerHTML`.

*) `DIV` is not a self-closing element, so the problem is that the first `div` doesn't close until it must (until the `BODY` tag closes). So your first `div` contains the second `div`, which contains the third, etc. When you change the `innerHTML` of the first div you overwrite all the other divs, so `document.getElementById(div#2)` returns `null`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html#div-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add text to individual divs like so.
The id's should almost be the same so you can use the same for loop to find the div and add the right text to it.

`$("#divId-"+i).text(array[i]);`

Or you can use document.getElementsByName to get all your divs that have the same name field.
Then just iterate over all of them and add the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/geNNa/107/)

Javascript:

```
var quizQuestions = ["Question1","Question2"];
for (var i in quizQuestions) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.id = quizQuestions[i]; 
    newElement.className = "quiz";
    newElement.innerHTML = quizQuestions[i];
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

CSS:

```
    .quiz {
        font-family     : Arial;
        text-align      : center;
        width           : 100px;
        height          : 15px;
        background      : #ccc;
        border          : 1px solid #000;
        box-shadow      : 1px 1px 5px -1px #000;
        padding         : 10px;
        margin-bottom   : 10px;
        cursor          : pointer;
     }
```